# Calling Awaitable Methods in Property Accessor [Windows Store Apps/Metro Apps]

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a custom class (to simplify stuff, I have stripped down the codes):

```
public class AlbumItem
{
   public StorageFile AlbumThumbnail { get; set;}
}
```

When I bind this to a ListView:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="100" Background="#FFabe372">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="{Binding AlbumSource}" Margin="10" Stretch="Uniform"></Image>
                    <TextBlock Margin="20 5" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource  AlbumListViewItemStyle}" Text="{Binding AlbumDisplayText}"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>

            </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

The `Image`'s source is set to `AlbumSource`, as I have thought to implement `AlbumSource` as a `Get`-only property:

```
public class AlbumItem
{
   public StorageFile AlbumThumbnail { get; set;}

   public BitmapImage AlbumSource
   {
       get
       {
          BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
          bmp.SetSource(await AlbumThumbnail.OpenReadAsync());
          return bmp;
       }
   }
}
```

As expected I can't use the `await` keyword in the accessor method, at the same time I cannot declare a property stub as an `async` method.

Can somebody point me in the correct direction? I may be trying a `Converter` later. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMHO property accessors should always return almost immediately. Long running operations should not execute inside a property accessor as this can have significant perfromance impacts because of the widely held assumption that an accessor is basically a variable read operation (i.e. properties can be accessed a lot, in loops, not cached for subsequent access etc).

I'd do something like this:

```
private async Task SetAlbumSourceAsync()
{
    bmp = new BitmapImage();
    var source = await AlbumThumbnail.OpenReadAsync();
    bmp.SetSource(source);
    RaisePropertyChanged("AlbumSource");
}

BitmapImage bmp;
public BitmapImage AlbumSource
{
    get
    {
        if (bmp == null) // might need a better sync mechanism to prevent reentrancy but you get the idea
            SetAlbumSourceAsync();

        return bmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! i got the idea, but Flavien's method solved my immediate need. I will explore your approach and see if I can get it up and working after this.

Comment: +1 This is the more correct answer. There is no technical reason that `async` properties can't exist; it was a design decision because an "asynchronous property" goes against the very concept of a property.

Comment: Yep, I have thus far implemented my properties using this method, and yes, it does not choke up my UI! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Not having an async modifier for properties is a major flaw in the C# component model. The problem lies in the inability of a property accessor to asynchronously call another method or lambda expression within the same thread as the client caller. This inability introduces various, non-trivial implementation complexities in situations where an accessor requires waitable access to async methods. Technically, get or set accessors are nothing more than separate methods and are implemented at compile-time as get_<property> and set_<property>. MSFT can and should correct this serious flaw.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `await`, the return type will have to be `Task<BitmapImage>`. If you want to be able to bind to your XAML, you need to return `BitmapImage`, and therefore can't use `await`. Use Task.Result instead:

```
public BitmapImage AlbumSource
{
    get
    {
       BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
       bmp.SetSource(AlbumThumbnail.OpenReadAsync().GetResults());
       return bmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: This method solves my problem, although dkackman's answer gave me another dimension to explore, thanks both! but I had to change `Task.Result` to `Task.GetResults()`... and my bad for the syntax error on `SetSource` (should be `SetSource()` instead).